# Integral $\int_0^b \frac{1-\cos ax}{x} dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

How can I evaluate this?
$$ I=\int_0^b \frac{1-\cos ax}{x} dx$$

I tried the following two approaches that do not work well:

1. Use the power series expansion
   $$ \frac{1-\cos ax}{x}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n)!} a^{2n}x^{2n-1}$$
   and integrate term by term to obtain
   $$I=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2n(2n)!}(ab)^{2n}.$$
   But how can I get a closed form expression?
2. Use the fact that
   $$ \frac 1x=\int_0^\infty e^{-tx} dt$$ and express $I$ as a double integral. After changing the order of integration, I obtained
   $$ I=\int_0^\infty \frac{1-e^{-bt}}{t}-\frac{1}{t^2+a^2}\{e^{-bt}(a\sin ab-t\cos ab)+t\}dt$$
   which is more compicated.

Comment: Are you supposed to know about the cosine integral function ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I have not heard about that.

Comment: Try using Feynman trick : differentiate with respect to $a$. It could help (may be).

Comment: This integral has no closed form and the answer you obtained is the most general.

Comment: One parameter between $a$ and $b$ is redundant (it can be removed through a substitution), hence you are asking for a primitive of $\frac{1-\cos x}{x}$, that is the same as asking for a primitive of $\frac{\sin x}{x^2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One have $\int_0^b \frac{1-\cos (a x)}{x} \, dx=-\text{Ci}(a b)+\log (a b)+\gamma$
where Ci is the cosine integral.